# How to add data in dynamic tables with RIDE in Robot Framework using Selenium2Library

Tags: selenium, robotframework

Hello I am new in Testing. And I want to test app by adding value in tables  which is dynamically get genrated. Please help me how to add value in table, using robot framework with RIDE.

```
*Settings*

 Library Selenium2Library  

 ** Variables **

 ${AddWhiteCityCode}    Pune

 ** Test Cases **

 Click AddWhiteCity
  Click AddWhiteCity

 ** Keywords **

   Click AddWhiteCity

      Input Text    xpath=(//td[contains(@class,"addWhiteCity"')])[1]  ${AddWhiteCityCode}
```

I have tried above syntax but gives Invalid Xpath syntax Error
Please help..

Thank you

sorry that is copy paste mistake i dont have single quote in my code.

This is my actual code.

`Input Text    xpath=(//td[contains(@class,"addWhiteCity")])[1]    ${AddWhiteCityCode}`

Comment: remove single quote in the xpath. It may work.

Answer (score 0):

You have single quotes. so that, you are getting invalid xpath error.

```
xpath=(//td[contains(@class,"addWhiteCity")])[1]
```